# Switch between XML files using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am using XML files as a layout for my html page and using javascript to load them
like this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","default.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

How can I switch between 2 or more layouts?

I'm using javascript/xml to load xml into html like this:

```
document.write('<ul id="horizontal-list">');
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("APP");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write('<li><a class="app_link" href="depiction.php?app=');
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write('&dl=');
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DOWNLOAD")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write('&install=');
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("INSTALL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write('">');
  document.write('<label class="app_label">');
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write('</label><img class="applicationIcon" src="');
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ICON")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write('"/></a></li>');
  }
document.write('</ul>');
```

*Note: I'm using a css stylesheet also.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the ajax a function like below and call the function with the path to your xml file:

```
function getXml($file){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET",$file,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
}
```

and you could also send your css file too (add second parameter to function and use jquery append function to append the stylesheet)